# Start with an element, apply function f repeatedly to each new element while adding them to a vector

Tags: clojure

In Clojure, is there some general purpose function (similar to higher order functions `map`, `filter`, `reduce`, where one starts, say, with a vector with one element, applies function `f` to the element, add the element to the vector, and apply the function to the new element, and continue as such until some condition is met.

Example: I have vector `[1]`, function `double`, and the function I am after, call it `f`, and, something like:

```
(take-while some-pred (f double 1))
```

which produces: `[1 2 4 8 16 32 . . .]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i guess you're talking about [iterate](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/iterate):

```
(take-while #(< % 1000) (iterate #(* 2 %) 1))
;;=> (1 2 4 8 16 32 64 128 256 512)
```

if you need vector, you can also use transducer:

```
(into [] (take-while #(< % 1000)) (iterate #(* 2 %) 1))
;; [1 2 4 8 16 32 64 128 256 512]
```